# SVG being overflow:hidden by bootstrap. Why?

Tags: css, svg, overflow, hidden

I have an inline SVG on my webpage. I'm dynamically adjusting it's start and end coordinates with some Javascript like so https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrYNaP?editors=1010.

However, in my webpage, I noticed that I can't see the svg due to:

```
svg:not(:root) {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Looks like it's coming from bootstrap (I think normalize.css). I can override it

```
svg {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

but then I get horizontal scroll bars and the svg is layered on top of every other div on the page (kinda needs to be in the background and z-index: -1 isn't working)

The weird thing is, when I view it in codepen, it doesn't have any of those issues.

What is going on and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
svg {
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```